# Disassembling numbers from the same variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

In JAVASCRIPT can each number from one variable be copied and transferred to another variable?
for example:

```
var number = 2456;
```

Can you copy numbers from this variable (2, 4, 5 and 6) and each of them place in a new variable?

for example:

```
var a = 2;
var b = 4;
var c = 5;
var d = 6;
```

Comment: `2456` is a single number. Numbers are represented as base 2 floating-point values. You can of course use the `/` and `%` operators to extract decimal digits from the value.

Comment: By number, the question obviously means digit.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to use an array instead of new variables. If so you can do this

```
var number = 2456,
    numbers = number.toString().split('').map(function(numberString){
       return Number(numberString);
    });
```

Comment: There is no need for `parseInt` here. Use `Number` instead.

Comment: Without `new`! That will return a number *object* instead of a primitive value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function :

```
var num = 123456;
NumberToArray(num);
alert(a);
alert(b);
alert(c);
alert(d);
function NumberToArray(num)
{
    var result = [];
    function div(val, by){  
        return (val - val % by) / by; 
    } 
    while (num != 0)
    {
        result.unshift(num%10);
        num = div(num, 10);
    }
    for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
    {
        window[String.fromCharCode(97+i)] = result[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure this works , when i try to open it in chrome blank page appears?

Comment: @silver, yep, because he used the `array.shift` method :-) `array.unshift` needed